# Position and reduce line labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

On the following code, I would like to get rid of all the labels, and only keep the ones in the end, also eliminate the legend. Thanks.

data:

```
Age gender  weight
20  M   121
22  F   142
24  M   170
26  F   180
28  M   177
30  F   210
32  M   197
34  F   213
36  M   169
38  F   155

ggplot(w, aes(Age, weight, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size=1.1) +geom_text(aes(label = gender))+
  scale_color_manual( values=c("blue","brown")) + 
  labs(title=paste( " line graph - r ")) +xlab("age") +ylab("weight (lbs)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the manual way is the easy way:

```
ggplot(w, aes(Age, weight, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size=1.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  annotate(geom="text", x = 36, y = 169, color = "brown", label = "M") + 
  annotate(geom="text", x = 38, y = 155, color = "blue", label = "F") + 
  scale_color_manual( values=c("blue","brown")) + 
  labs(title=paste( " line graph - r ")) +xlab("age") +ylab("weight (lbs)")
```

[image]

Another approach is to re-define the data, but subsetting that only leaves the last two points:

```
ggplot(w, aes(Age, weight, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size=1.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(data = w[w$Age > 35,], aes(label = gender), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual( values=c("blue","brown")) + 
  labs(title=paste( " line graph - r ")) +xlab("age") +ylab("weight (lbs)")
```